# Wordpress play video on frontpage from post

Tags: wordpress, video, mp4, frontpage

I have a post where I have a mp4 video. It is possible to play it on the frontpage? Now I have to go to the post, but I want to be able to play video from front page, not going to post.
Anyone have an idea how to do it?
I will be gratefull.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could get the content from the post and do some kind of parsing in order to retrieve the media element (iframe or other) and display it on your front page ?